# JLayer извлечение аудио-данных с mp3

Tags: java, jlayer

Как в библиотеке JLayer можно извлечь аудио-данные с одного mp3 файла в другой?
Вот то, что я пытался сделать:

```
public Cutter(FileInputStream input, int start, int end) throws IOException, DecoderException, BitstreamException
{
    Decoder dcr = new Decoder();
    Bitstream bStream = new Bitstream(input);
    Header hdr = bStream.readFrame();
    FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("tmp.mp3");
    while(start != bStream.header_pos())
    {
        Obuffer buf = dcr.decodeFrame(hdr, bStream);
        SampleBuffer buffer = new SampleBuffer(dcr.getOutputFrequency(), dcr.getOutputChannels());
        dcr.setOutputBuffer(buffer);
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < buffer.getBufferLength(); i++)
                output.write(buffer.getBuffer()[i]);
        }
        catch (IOException e) { }
    }
```

Comment: Это очень неэффективно, но по идее это запишет в файл декодированный WAVE поток без заголовка

Comment: я пишу аудио-редактор, который должен резать и клеить mp3. В файле mp3 фреймы состоят из 2х частей: заголовка и данных. Вот как извлечь данные и как узнать время текущего куска я не знаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А вообще, я года полтора назад работал с JLayer. Вот я выкладывал код по декодированию MP3: [MP3Decoder](http://code.google.com/p/java-audio-player/source/browse/src/maryb/player/decoder/MP3Decoder.java?repo=player)

Comment: у меня вопрос по коду: что возвращает метод getBuffer();?